# Sports Scheduling Minizinc

Tags: network-programming, resource-scheduling, minizinc

We plan a tournament with 8 teams, where every team plays
every other team exactly once. The tournament is played on 7
days, each team playing on each day. The games are
scheduled in 7 venues, and each team should play in each
venue exactly once.
As part of the TV arrangements, some preassignments are
done: We may either ﬁx the game between two particular
teams to a ﬁxed day and venue, or only state that some team
must play on a particular day at a given venue. The objective is
to complete the schedule, so that all constraints are satisﬁed.

i need help to make this problem in minizinc.
Thank you

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried so far?

Comment: set of int:numTeam=1..8;
set of int:numCity=7;
set of int:numDay = 7;

int:partidos_por_dia = 4;
int:partidos_ciudad = 4;
array[numDay, numCity] of var numTeam: resultado;        I've tried but i only know to declare this

Comment: Please update your question with this information, this way you can properly format your source. The next problem is, that people on SO typically are hesitant to just generate working solutions for questions like this. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html